# sed: replace one or more group values in lines that match

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to change a configuration variable in a file. Basically, the file has multiple lines in this format:

```
$config['var'] = 'val';
```

The desired output:

```
$config['var'] = 'new_value';
```

This is what I have come up so far:

```bsh
sed -i -r "s/^\$config\['var'\]\s*=\s*(..*);$/\1'new_value'/g" config.cfg
```

I've tried answers from what seems like countless of similar questions here, but haven't had any luck. Any clues what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to include `config` or `var` in the search pattern. Use `/^$config\['var'\]/` before `s/…/…/` to perform search and replace only within lines that start with `$config['var']`. This makes the whole task easier.

```
sed "/^\$config\['var'\]/ s/=.*;/= 'new_value';/"
```

Note `$` is escaped because of double quotes. It's no longer escaped when it gets to `sed`. The tool treats it literally because it's not at the end.